# What does Twig's 'default' filter do if no argument is provided?

Tags: twig, timber

I understand how the `default` filter would behave if it were used like so: `items|default(posts)`

However, I stumbled across some code where it was used but no arg was passed:

```
{% if ( posts|default ) %}


{% endif %}
```

It's possible that it's actually not doing anything and is just incomplete or boilerplate code, but I wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not passing any arguments the `default` filter will result in `twig` returning an empty string (`''`). It's also worth to mention that in `twig`, if you test an empty string it will result in `false`.

So in this case if the `post` variable is not defined, false or an empty string, the filter will return an empty string and the if will return the value `false` thus ignoring the code inside the code block

---

```html
{% set foo = bar|default %}
{{ foo == '' ? 'empty string' : 'not an empty string' }}

{% if '' %}
    Do something
{% else %}
    Don't do anything
{% endif %}


--------------------------------

{% set var1 = false %}
{% set var2 = {} %}


{% if var1 | default %}
    Do sthing with var1
{% else %}
    Don't do anything with var1
{% endif %}


{% if var2 | default %}
    Do sthing with var2
{% else %}
    Don't do anything with var2
{% endif %}


{% if var3 | default %}
    Do sthing with var3
{% else %}
    Don't do anything with var3
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/wogwe0)